# I am trying to write a jolt transformation for below input -

Tags: json, list, jolt

This is an input that needs to be transformed using Jolt Transformation to obtain the expected output.

I am trying to write a jolt transformation for the below input. but It's not matched with the expected output.

My Input:

```json
[
  {
    "external_id": 855644012615,
    "order_id": 4551472709703,
    "processed_at": "2022-08-30T02:40:26-04:00",
    "tracking_number": 4.201110410179302e+24,
    "refund_line_items": [
      {
        "order_line_item_id": 11544859803719,
        "quantity": 6,
        "line_item": {
          "name": "FLORENCIA RED MULTI - RED MULTI / 6 / 634",
          "product_id": 6586562773063,
          "properties": [
            {
              "name": "UPCA",
              "value": "195945037714"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

expected output

```json
[ 
  {
    "externalId" : 855644012615,
    "orderExternalId" : 4551472709703,
    "partyIdFrom" : "NA",
    "destinationFacilityId" : "",
    "partyIdTo" : "NA",
    "status" : "PURCH_SHIP_CREATED",
    "type" : "SALES_RETURN",
    "estimatedShipCost" : "0",
    "packages" : [ 
      {
        "packageSeqId" : "",
        "trackingCode" : 4.201110410179302E24,
        "items" : [ 
          {
            "sku" : "195945037714",
            "quantity" : 6
          } 
        ]
      } 
    ]
  } 
]
```

I am using this spec for transforming the input JSON.
Can you please help to find out my mistake?

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "partyIdFrom": "_NA_",
        "destinationFacilityId": "",
        "externalPartyIdFrom": "",
        "partyIdTo": "_NA_",
        "status": "PURCH_SHIP_CREATED",
        "type": "SALES_RETURN",
        "estimatedShipCost": "0",
        "packageSeqId": ""
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "external_id": "[&1].externalId",
        "order_id": "[&1].orderExternalId",
        "partyIdFrom": "[&1].partyIdFrom",
        "destinationFacilityId": "[&1].destinationFacilityId",
        "partyIdTo": "[&1].partyIdTo",
        "status": "[&1].status",
        "type": "[&1].type",
        "estimatedShipCost": "[&1].estimatedShipCost",
        "packageSeqId": "[&1].packages[&1].packageSeqId",
        "tracking_number": "[&1].packages[&1].trackingCode",
        "refund_line_items": {
          "*": {
            "quantity": "[&2].packages[#5].items[&3].quantity",
            "line_item": {
              "properties": {
                "*": {
                  "value": "[&6].packages[#4].items[&1].sku"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Some values of some attributes in the desired output don't exist within the input such as `status`, `type` don't exist. Are they some fixed values to be displayed?

Comment: Yes, status and type both are fixed values.

Answer (score 0):

So far so good, just need to add the line

```json
"@(3,quantity)": "[&6].packages[#4].items[&1].quantity"
```

into the `"properties"` object, and replace the leaf nodes of some attributes with `&` characters in order to replicate their key names. eg, no need to write them repeatedly. Those key-value pairs are :

```json
"partyIdFrom": "[&1].&",
"destinationFacilityId": "[&1].&",
"partyIdTo": "[&1].&",
"status": "[&1].&",
"type": "[&1].&",
"estimatedShipCost": "[&1].&",
"packageSeqId": "[&1].packages[&1].&",
```

indeed using just one line

```json
"*": "[&1].&",
```

is enough but the order would be mixed up for this case.

As a result, prefer using the following transformation spec :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "partyIdFrom": "_NA_",
        "destinationFacilityId": "",
        "externalPartyIdFrom": "",
        "partyIdTo": "_NA_",
        "status": "PURCH_SHIP_CREATED",
        "type": "SALES_RETURN",
        "estimatedShipCost": "0",
        "packageSeqId": ""
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "external_id": "[&1].externalId",
        "order_id": "[&1].orderExternalId",
        "partyIdFrom": "[&1].&", //should be converted to this
        "destinationFacilityId": "[&1].&", //should be converted to this
        "partyIdTo": "[&1].&", //should be converted to this
        "status": "[&1].&", //should be converted to this
        "type": "[&1].&", //should be converted to this
        "estimatedShipCost": "[&1].&", //should be converted to this
        "packageSeqId": "[&1].packages[&1].&", //should be converted to this
        "tracking_number": "[&1].packages[&1].trackingCode",
        "refund_line_items": {
          "*": {
            "quantity": "[&2].packages[#5].items[&3].&",
            "line_item": {
              "properties": {
                "*": {
                  "value": "[&6].packages[#4].items[&1].sku",
                  "@(3,quantity)": "[&6].packages[#4].items[&1].quantity" //should be added
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Btw, another option would be using **`#`** wildcards as in the following example line

```json
"#PURCH_SHIP_CREATED": "[&1].status",
```

The **default** transformation spec wouldn't be needed through use of this manner.

Answer (score 0):

The final answer of my input JSON that I expected.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "partyIdFrom": "_NA_",
        "destinationFacilityId": "",
        "externalPartyIdFrom": "",
        "partyIdTo": "_NA_",
        "status": "PURCH_SHIP_CREATED",
        "type": "SALES_RETURN",
        "estimatedShipCost": "0",
        "packageSeqId": ""
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "external_id": "[&1].externalId",
        "order_id": "[&1].orderExternalId",
        "partyIdFrom": "[&1].partyIdFrom",
        "destinationFacilityId": "[&1].destinationFacilityId",
        "partyIdTo": "[&1].partyIdTo",
        "status": "[&1].status",
        "type": "[&1].type",
        "estimatedShipCost": "[&1].estimatedShipCost",
        "packageSeqId": "[&1].packages[#3].packageSeqId",
        "tracking_number": "[&1].packages[#3].trackingCode",
        "refund_line_items": {
          "*": {
            "quantity": "[&3].packages[#5].items[#2].quantity",
            "line_item": {
              "properties": {
                "*": {
                  "value": "[&6].packages[#8].items[#5].sku"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: No need to repeat the same words for the attributes whose key-value pairs remain identical such as for `"partyIdFrom": "[&1].partyIdFrom"`, just use "partyIdFrom": "[&1].&".

Comment: Thanks  Barbaros Özhan
I will remember that.